# iPhone SDK MKPlacemark

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I need help with the MapKit framework. I am new to iPhone development. 
I have a webview that loads from a url with 3 params like this:

in viewDidLoad method from the view controller:

```
NSString *hoUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://fastenergy.clavis-solutions.de/?iwidth=%@&iheight=%@&zipcode=%@", hString, wString, zipcode];
```

I can't get the zipcode. I am calling this before the url:

```
locationController = [[HoCLController alloc] init];
locationController.delegate = self;
[locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and in this method from HoCLController.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

, I call

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
    [geocoder setDelegate:self];
    [geocoder start];
```

Then I have these 2 methods

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", placemark.postalCode);

}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```

The question is , how can I get the zipcode in the url?

Thank you and please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have already the answer in your question.
`placemark.postalcode` consists of your zipcode.
Just make sure, that all your variables consist the right value.

```
zipcode = placemark.postalCode;
```

Should be the answer, if i get your question right.

Comment: First thank you for your answer.
But if I do `zipcode = placemark.postalCode;` in the `- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {` method, then in viewDidLoad I receive null. I need the zipCode variable in viewDidLoad method.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have properties in your main class for zipcode? @property (nonatomic) NSInteger zipcode; something like this. you need to get the value from HoCLController. This link maybe helps: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ chapter 7 and 9

Comment: In HoCLController.h I have `NSString *zipCode;` since the postalCode is NSString, I also have `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *zipCode;`. In HoCLController.m I have `@synthesize zipCode;` And in the view Controller I try to call it like: `locationController = [[HoCLController alloc] init];
 locationController.delegate = self;` `NSLog(@"zip code: %@", locationController.zipCode);` and I get null.

Comment: maybe without locationController = [[HoCLController alloc] init]; locationController.delegate = self; ? then you alloc it again and the values are null?!

Comment: The problem is that the reverseGeocoder didFindPlacemark method is called at the end of the application even if I call geocoder start in viewDidLoad method. The application runs normally and at the end it calls the geocoder so I can't grab the placemark in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Then you could source out the code (NSString *hoUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://fastenergy.clavis-solutions.de/?iwidth=%@&iheight=%@&zipcode=%@", hString, wString, zipcode];) into another function which is first called, if the Values are loaded and not before.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
```

You have to pass coordinate in this method. So check if coord is not nil.I guess this is what you want.

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh Ok, forget it..
I miss something, sorry

*Are you subclassing `CLLocationManager` ???
If not, why are you allocating like this: `locationManager = [[HoCLController alloc] init];` instead of this:`self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];` I'm sorry if I'm getting something wrong, but think i'm giving you the answer..*